# Is it necessary to add POI for reading and writing Excel Sheets in JAVA?

Tags: java, excel

Is it necessary to add Apache POI and similar libraries to read and write Excel Files in JAVA? Is there any predefined JAVA library for reading and writing Excel Sheets?

Comment: Java does not ship with excel support out-of-the-box, so yes you'll need POI or similar.